# UML, trying to unterstand dependency relations

Tags: java, dependencies, uml, class-diagram

Im trying to unterstand more about dependency relations.
Obviously, a dependency relation is always given if there is an association relation.
If I understand correctly, an association occurs when an object of a class is created.
So I programmed the following 2 code's, to practice it a bit more.

#### Case 1

```
class A {}
class B extends A {}
class C {
    A a;
    public C(B b) {
        a = b;
    }
}
```

The diagram should have a generalization from B on A because of the "extends", a association from C on A because C has an instance variable of type A and a dependency from C on B because B is used as a parametre in the constructer of C.

[image: [UML for 1. Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCkKt.png)]

#### Case 2

```
class A {}
class B {
    static A test() {
        return new A();
    }
}
class C {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a = B.test();
    }
}
```

I imagined that B has a dependency to A. And C has a dependency to B.
But does C have an additional dependency to A, because there is a 'A' attribute in the main method?

[image: [UML for 2. Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMCIK.png)]

Answer (score 1):

There is no single mapping from language constructs to UML concepts.  So diagrams derived from code only represents one possible design among severals.

The first diagram is consistent with your code.  A couple of remarks:

- You show a navigable association from C to A, which is fine, but you do not need to use an arrow unless you want to express that navigation should be easy.
- You must use open arrow heads instead of plain arrow heads; this is the standard notation and it will avoid any confusion.

The second case is interesting regarding C:

- a variable in an operation is not sufficient to justify an association, because local variables in operation exist just for the time of a single execution of that operation  and not accessible outside the operation.

  The case of `main()` is somewhat particular in this regard in the case of Java. I would highly recommend to stick to the principle and not to show an association.  Nevertheless, I think that you have freedom of expression and could interpret -- if this is the way you see your design -- that main being executed and lasting for the full time of execution, there is a de facto association.
- The A and the B do appear neither in the properties nor in the signatures of C's functions, but only in their bodies. So from the point of view of the design, there is no dependency, because you could very well implement the operations differently.  I would therefore in general recommend not show such implementation-dependent dependencies, **unless your diagram is meant to specify or document implementation details** (UML is agnostic about its potential usage).

  Again, the case of `main()` is somewhat special, because it generally binds together the main elements of the design and therefore uses in general only classes that are needed at the highest level of your design. You may therefore want to show these dependencies; not showing them could mislead to think that your class could make sense without those classes, whereas its purpose is really to bind them together.

Comment: _You should use open arrow_ no! You **must** since otherwise it's plain wrong.